# Explanation of a problem about vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Please could you explain for me the following problem. For me it is all about the understanding of the notation not solving the  problem:

for f,g: M → K we define

f+g: M → K by f+g(x) = f(x)+g(x) and for k ∈ K we define

k·f : M → K by k·f(x) = k·f(x)

Prove that abb(M, K) := {f : M → K mapping} has a structure of a K-vector space.

Comment: They are defining the addition of "vectors" and the scalar multiplication.  Now check it.

Comment: thanks, yes, but what does abb(M, K) means? is it a pair? if yes of what?

Comment: It is the set of all functions from $M$ to $K$.  An element of this set is a function.  I do not know what "abb" is to stand for.

Comment: Abb stands for mapping from the german Abbildung

Comment: so the range of each function should be in the field K? Actually I can't relate this to the definition of a vector space which defined as (V, +, .) where +: V x V→V and . : k x V → V because I can't understand why f,g: M → K and not f,g: M → M

Comment: The point is that you can "add" functions because you can add their values in $K$.  Same thing for scaling.

Comment: If $M = \{1, 2\}$, I can add functions $f, g : M \to \mathbb{R}$.  For instance, if $f(1)=4$, $f(2) = 17$, $g(1)=-1$ and $g(2)=10$, then $f+g : M \to \mathbb{R}$ makes sense as a function that maps $1$ to $f(1)+g(1)=4-1=3$ and maps $2$ to $f(2)+g(2)=17+10=27$.  I can likewise define $7\cdot f$ as the function that maps $1$ to $28$ and $2$ to $119$.

Comment: ok this confuses me again because M in your example M is not a set f functions but numbers on which the functions f,g are applied

Comment: No one said that $M$ is a set of functions.  It is $\mathrm{Abb}(M,K)$ which is a set of functions, namely the set of all functions from $M$ to $K$.

Comment: ok so we have to prove e.g. that f+g ∈ Abb(,) and k.f ∈ Abb(,) and so on

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: Thanks, but honestly the notation is extremely unintuitive

Comment: Why?  In English, we would call this something like $\mathrm{Map}(M,\mathbb{R})$, as it is literally the set of all maps (functions) from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: may be for you,  actually i face difficulties only because of the notation. we receive in the universities mathematical problems to solve with such notation without explanation by the prefessor

Comment: lastly, can we conclude that the functions inherit the properties of the field K concerning the commutativity and the identity and so on?

Answer (score 1):

The space Abb$(M,K)$ is a set with mappings as elements. So if we want to define a vector-space structure on this set, the mappings are now called "vectors".

If you want to equip the space Abb$(M,K)$ with a $K$-vector-space structure you need to define how to add two elements of this space - so you have to define an addition of two mappings $f,g: M \to K$.

The definition you gave is the pointwise definition of addition. It means that the element $f \oplus g$ in the space Abb$(M,K)$ is defined by how it works as a mapping, namely: The mapping $f \oplus g$ maps a point $x \in M$ to the sum of the points $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in $K$.

It is similar for the scalar multiplication. The definition given here is again pointwise, so the element $k \otimes f$ for a mapping $f \in $ Abb$(M,K)$ and a $k \in K$ is defined by how it operates as a mapping. The mapping $k \otimes m$ maps a point $x \in M$ to the product of $k$ and $f(x)$ in $K$.

Comment: Thanks. So f,g: M → K is the mapping of two mappings that goes from the set M to Field K? and how could you understand it as a pointwise notation?

Comment: With $f,g: M \to K$ I just meant a short formulation of $f: M \to K$ and $g: M \to K$. 
Here, $f$ and $g$ are both mappings from the set $M$ to the field $K$. The element $f \oplus g$ in Abb$(M,K)$, defined as above, is ALSO a mapping from the set $M$ to the field $K$. That is the main thing about vector spaces: The addition of two "vectors" (mappings in our case) should be an element of the same space (so in our case: should be a mapping again).

This definition is pointwise because the element $f \oplus g$ is defined by how it operates on each "point" $x \in M$.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. So can we notate the vector space this way + : Abb (,) x Abb (,) → Abb (,). similarly for the multiplication? I mean the set on which we apply the vector space properties is the pair (,) ∈ Abb (,), where ∈ ,  ∈ 